# How to implement "NO solder paste" pad in Altium

Tags: altium, layout

I'm designing a footprint for [J-Link 10-pin Needle Adapter](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/accessories/adapters/10-pin-needle-adapter/). The pads need "no solder paste". I've looked around all configurations for the pad but didn't find a method to remove solder paste, so my question is how to design this kind of "no solder paste" pad in Altium efficiently?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey look. It's Tag-Connect. The reason you might not be able to find instructions is because it's trivial if you know what a solder mask is supposed to do. Just remove the solder mask in the padstack used for the pin. No solder mask = no hole in the soldermask = no solder applied.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the properties of the pad.

Set the Paste Mask Expansion to a large negative number (with absolute magnitude greater than the largest dimension of the pad).

Comment: +1 For a round pad slightly more than *half* the diameter of the pad. Too-large expansions can apparently cause hard-to-find clearance violations, at least they can with solder mask.